# Unrecognized targetFramework in web.config

Tags: azure-web-app-service

Just signed for Azure, buildt my first ASP.net website i VS2019 .NET 4.7.2 (runs fine locally) published to my new webresource on Azure and I immediately get "Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive." from web configure, also at the bottom Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.8810; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.8745

My web.config has this offending `<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2"/>`

I am totally lost already. Can' find anything to change anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem should come from the application pool settings on azure.

From your describle, the setting is 2.0. Try to change it to 4.0.

Comment: Finally found the Configure submenu General settings which had .net version 3.5 instead of 4.7. Changing that made the difference. Why it displayed 2.0 I don't know.